# Find a specific word in an object using strpos in php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to set up a test question that will find certain words in a short answer. The words, which will mark the answer as correct, will be stored as values in an object. I was trying to figure out how to do it with strpos(), but every alternative that I come up with gives me a blank screen.

PHP:

```
$myJSON = file_get_contents('quiz.json');
$json = json_decode($myJSON); 
foreach($json as $value) {
    foreach($value->answer as $index => $options) {
        $findme = "application";
        $pos = strpos($options, $findme);
        if ($pos === true) {
            echo $options;
    //echo $value->text->type->answer;
     //echo ($index. ' '. $options . '<br>');
        //echo current($value);
        }
    }

}

JSON:

{

    "question1": {
        "text": "What are the two types of permission lists that DSA concentrates on?",
        "type": "short_answer",
        "answer": {
                "1": "application", 
                "2": "row-level"
        }
    },
    "question2": {
        "text": "What are the building blocks for EmpowHR Security?",
        "type": "short_answer",
        "answer": {
                "1": "permission lists"
        }
    },
    "question3": {
        "text": "Who is the bomb?",
        "type": "short_answer",
        "answer": {
                "1": "permission"
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: This is quite unclear. Please give concrete examples of what the results should be. Also, what is `"application"` and why is it hardcoded?

Comment: Op added the JSON obj to show what comes from quiz.json. To me this seems like an issue with parsing an obj into the strpos function. Likely the answer will involve converting the json into an array then running it through the loop.

Comment: `if($pos === true)`. Always `false`. It's either `false` or a unsigned integer, which could even be zero.

Comment: I used if($pos === true) based off of the logic in Example #1 in the PHP manual, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.

Answer (score 2):

Tested the following using your given JSON file.

**Important:** First I added the `, true` to `$json = json_decode($myJSON);` --> `$json = json_decode($myJSON, true);` This turns the obj into an array

After var_dumping the json encoded I noticed you had mixed string and array types in the level you were trying to parse, so used `in_array()` to filter out the strings and only iterate through the arrays and was able to locate all instances of the "answers" section in its current build within that obj.

```
$stmt = NULL;
$find = "application";
$myJSON = file_get_contents('quiz.json');
$json = json_decode($myJSON, true);

foreach( $json as $content ){
  foreach( $content as $target){
    if(is_array($target)){
      // we must find the key of the value within the next level of the array
      // and use it as index for the value $target to use in strpos() --> $target[$index]
      foreach($target as $index => $value){           
        if(strpos($target[$index], $find) !== false){
          $stmt = '<span>'.$target[$index].': CORRECT</span>';
        }
      }
    }    
  }
}

echo $stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the code that I will be merging with doesn't use it as an array. I got some ideas from your syntax, such as using current(), as I've read that it can iterate over objects as well as arrays. I tried using curly brackets instead of the square brackets. Still, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $json as $question=>$content ){
   foreach( $content as $key=>$value ){
      if( strpos( $value, 'applikation' ) !== false
         echo $value;
      }
   }
}
```

strpos returns the found position and false if not found.

returnvalue === true: allways false

returnvalue == true: false if not found or found on first position (0), true if found after first position  (all numbers != 0 are true)

returnvalue !== false: correct result